# I'm trying to get the logout button to appear when I have a token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, navigation, js-cookie

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import BurgerMenu from "./BurgerMenu";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get("token");
    console.log(token);
    setToken(token);
  }, []);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    Cookies.remove("token");
    navigate("/login");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <BurgerMenu />
      <header className="border-[1px] border-[#FF2A70] border-transparent">
        <div className="flex sm:flex w-[full] sm:justify-around items-center py-6 p-5">
          <img src="/assets/Logo.png" alt="NightClub Logo" />
          <nav className="hidden sm:block sm:uppercase">
            <ul>
              <li className="flex gap-5 justify-between font-bold">
                <NavLink className="hover:text-[#FF2A70]" to="/">
                  Home
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="hover:text-[#FF2A70]" to="/blog">
                  Blog
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="hover:text-[#FF2A70]" to="/booking">
                  Booking
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink className="hover:text-[#FF2A70]" to="/contactus">
                  Contact us
                </NavLink>
                {token ? (
                  <button className="uppercase" onClick={handleLogout}>
                    Log out
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <NavLink className="hover:text-[#FF2A70]" to="/login">
                    Log in
                  </NavLink>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Hi every one. I'm trying to get the logout button to appear when I have a token. And when I'm logged out, a login button should appear instead. At the same time, I get "undefined" displayed in the console next to Header.js:13. Anyone able to catch the problem?

Comment: Hello. So when the Header is rendered, this function is called

useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get("token");
    console.log(token);
    setToken(token);
  }, []);

The token might not be have been set and since that function is only rendered once on initialization the state would not change if the token is updated after the rendering

Comment: Okay. So what should I do to fix the problem. Because there is also no log out button in the navigation when I log in. I need to update my page before it shows up. :(

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is add the `pathname` from `useLocation` as a dependency in your `useEffect`, so when you go from the login page, set your cookie token and go to another page, the `pathname` will change and the `useEffect` can run to check if a token is present like such:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // only run this if there is no token present in the state

  if (!token) {
    const cookieToken = Cookies.get("token");
    console.log(token);
    if (cookieToken) {
      setToken(cookieToken);
    }
  }

}, [pathname]);
```

Also, I see you are not resetting the `token` state to null once you logout. Thus when you click `logout`, the cookie is removed, but because the token is still in the `token` state, the logout button will still be present and thus you will not see the login link. What you could do is the following:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

const handleLogout = () => {
  Cookies.remove("token");
  setToken(null);
  navigate("/login");
};
```

Initialise token to `null`, and set it to `null` once you click the logout button. This will ensure the login button appears when you have no token and the logout button is present once you have the token.

Finally, ideally you do not want to check for the token and the set the token this way in the `Header` component. You should check for the `token` in an auth wrapper component (which renders pages based on whether the user is authenticated or not), and save the login status and relevant user props in a global state, which can then be accessed by the `Header` component which can then render the `login` and `log out` buttons appropriately.